# How to Express Improper Prior Distributions by Mathematical Formulas

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

This time I target the following two-class Bayesian logistic regression as statistical models.

$$y_n \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(q_n)$$
$$q_n = \sigma (\beta_0 + x_n \beta_1)$$

where $n$ is the index of the data and $\sigma$ is the logistic function.

Since I assume $\beta_0 + x_n \beta_1$ as the linear predictor (the independent variable of the logistic activation function), I have two parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, and I want to express that their prior distributions independently follow an improper uniform distribution, the support of which each probability density function is the set of real numbers.
Is it appropriate to write

$$\beta_0, \beta_1 \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(-\infty, \infty), i.i.d.$$

in this case?
I'm particularly concerned about the appropriateness of writing i.i.d.
If there is a more appropriate way to express this, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-regular uniform distribution"?

Comment: Sorry for the somewhat inaccurate wording. I’ve changed the term "non-regular" to the more accurate and better known "improper".

Comment: I see. The uniform distribution over the real line is not well-defined. Maybe you can place some constraint on the maximum values of $|\beta_0|$ and $|\beta_1|$? Then you can say $\beta_0, \beta_1 \sim \text{Unif}[-\beta_{\max}, \beta_{\max}]$, which is well defined.

Comment: I appreciate your thought-provoking response.
What I wanted to ask is not where I can define the improper uniform distribution as each prior distribution of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, but whether I can use the term "i.i.d." here.

Comment: Oh I see. Using i.i.d. should be fine here imo. You can also write "We assume that $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are aproiri independent and follow the same distribution given by ...".

Comment: I'm grateful for your kind response.
My question has been answered.
I was particularly curious as to whether I can use the term "i.i.d." here, even thought $x_n$ has certain units, e.g. kg.
This is because the units of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are different in this case.

Comment: Random variable generally refers to the numerical value of it. If you want to be super specific, you can also add that this corresponds only to their numerical value (without units). Usually that is quite clear from the context.

Comment: Thank you for your further guidance.
Certainly, specifying that it is i.i.d. if the units are ignored (omitted) would clarify what I am trying to show.